# How to disown a process opened by plugin? (vim-rmarkdown)

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-rmarkdown

as I said in the title I'm talking about [vim-rmarkdown](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown), I have this in my `init.vim` (I'm using neovim) to compile the `.rmd` file to a pdf.

```
autocmd Filetype rmd nnoremap <F5> :w<Space><bar><Space>RMarkdown!<Space>pdf<Space>latex_engine="pdflatex"<enter>
```

The plugin opens the pdf on it's own but the process is not disowned so I can't leave it open and continue working in vim. I've tried several things but every time I add something behind the `:RMarkdown!` command it always takes it as a argument for rendering the pdf (even with `<bar>`), so I always end up with failed rendering. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note if the the answer to this turns out to be "the plugin has to support this explicitly", I'm one of the plugin maintainers and am listening ;-) We'd be glad to support this, I just don't know how it needs to be done, so this question is quite relevant.

Comment: @Caleb I opened a issue about this yesterday on the plugins github page and alerque said that it could be done with either job control or a shell background function. But IDK how to do any of it so...